# Python GUI with Tkinter and Multiple Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, user-interface, tkinter

So I realized I did some beginner mistakes in my code. So I made a few steps back to the first attemps. I have an small GUI with one window.

Now I have some questions:

1. why does also greet has to have (self) ?
2. how do I call (is call the right word here?) greet from another py file?

Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *

class MyFirstGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!").pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet).pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=self.quit).pack()

    def greet(self):
        print('Hello')

    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For your first question take a look at this post: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does also greet has to have (self) ?

Other program languages use `@` to define different class attribute however python uses `self` for this. `self` is used within a class to let the class know that there is a class attribute or method that can be accessed from anywhere in the class (or from outside the class).

Example benefit: If we have a function that updates a variable and a call to that function we will need to use `global` and the call to the function must occur after the function has been defined in the code.

like this:

```
x = 0

def update_x():
    global x
    x+=1
    print(x)

update_x()
```

However in a class we can avoid the use of `global` and define all of our methods (functions in a class using self) after the code that calls those methods allowing us to keep things a little cleaner.

Like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.update_x()

    def update_x(self):
        self.x +=1
        print(self.x)

MyClass()
```

> how do I call (is call the right word here?) greet from another py file?

You will need to import the file just like you would import a library.

For example if say your main program is in `main.py` and have another `py` file in the same directory called `test.py` and you wish to call on something in the `test.py` file from the `main.py` file you will need to import the `test.py` file on the `main.py` file

For most cases of files that fall under the same directory do this:

```
import test
```

Sometimes your program is in a package of some kind and you may need to provide the import like this.

```
import package_name.test
```

you can use this as a test example:

`test.py` file contains:

```
def plus_one(number):
    x = number + 1
    return x
```

`main.py` file contains:

```
import test

x = test.plus_one(5)
print(x)
```

Console output should be:

```
6
```

Comment: @K-Doe Glad to help. If my answer works for you please make sure to select the check box next to the answer.

Comment: Sure! :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

*1.* *why does also greet has to have (self) ?*

The function `greet()` is a function of your `MyFirstGUI` class, you can see  that when you bind this function to the `greet_button` the function is put after `self`. It means that the function has a link to `self` (which is `MyFirstGUI`). This link is made by putting self in the function definition.

*2. how do I call (is call the right word here?) greet from another py file?*
(I'm not sure I understand what you ask)

Yes call is right ! If you want to call this function from another file, you would have to import the `MyFirstGUI` in your main file and create an instance of this object.

mainFile.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from guiFile import MyFirstGUI

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
my_guy.greet()
root.mainloop()
```

guiFile.py:

```
from tkinter import *    
class MyFirstGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!").pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet).pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=self.quit).pack()

    def greet(self):
        print('Hello')

    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```

Comment: To be clear when a function is in side of a class and uses `self` it is called a method. On the same note if a variable is being assigned with the use of `self.` it is called a class attribute.

Comment: Hi thanks for your explanation, it worked fine and I understand what's going on! Is there also a way to use greet without having the GUI to start?

Comment: The code does what it should, but if MyFirstGUI is showed and I push the Quit button it says : "name 'root' is not defined". But root = Tk() is in the code?

Comment: Ho yes, it's probably because when you press `quit()` in one window, the `self.master.destroy()` delete the `root`instance... Maybe you should replace it by `self.destroy()` to quit only the window you want to quit !

Comment: @Mike-SMT Just attribute or instance attribute. A class attribute would be on the _class_. It may be read via `self.` if the instance has no such attribute, but to assign, you have to go via the class.